# How to modify datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable but I can't modify row value when I use below command.

```
Int64 quantity = Convert.ToInt64(txtQuantity.Text);
blOfferList_temp.Rows[RowNo - 1]["Quantity"] = quantity;
```

It is just possible when I use

```
tblOfferList_temp.Rows[RowNo - 1]["Quantity"] = 100;
```

And I really need the fist one . Is there any way to modify datatable using variables??

I want to explain more about my problem

first of all I have a datatable which I define like this

```
private DataTable tblOfferList_temp;
```

then in a method I create datatable like this

```
tblOfferList_temp = new DataTable();
tblOfferList_temp.Columns.Add("OfferID", typeof(string));
tblOfferList_temp.Columns.Add("RowNo", typeof(Int16));
tblOfferList_temp.Columns.Add("SMCode", typeof(string));
tblOfferList_temp.Columns.Add("SSCode", typeof(string));
tblOfferList_temp.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int64));
tblOfferList_temp.Columns.Add("TotalArea", typeof(Int64));
tblOfferList_temp.Columns.Add("TotalValue", typeof(Int64));
```

after calling this method in form_load I have to store data into it and then show and modify its data in case needed

the store and show method works fine

(I call store method with button next and show with button prev and also with next )

and modify method ,which I have problem with , is needed after showing.

I don't know how to explain better . after prev button controls show the prev row values and I need to modify them and store them in the datatable with next button click

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: It just don't change the value I really don't know why.

Comment: No matter how I change the value it always works. You have to reveal more code like how do you create the `DataTable` etc.

Comment: I added some extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a typo in the first example—`blOfferList_temp` instead of `tblOfferList_temp`.

Aside from that, the only difference between these two code snippets is that in the first one, you are assigning a value of type `Int64` and in the second you are assigning an `Int32` (the default for an unspecified numeric). If using just `100` works fine, try casting to an `Int32` instead:

```
Int32 quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
blOfferList_temp.Rows[RowNo - 1]["Quantity"] = quantity;
```

If `txtQuantity.Text` has values in it that don't fit in an `Int32` you will have to change your datatable to accept `Int64`s instead, and that's a whole different story.

(I'd also recommend putting some error handling in case `txtQuantity.Text` doesn't contain a parseable string but of course that's very dependent on where that value is coming from.)

Comment: thanks for the answer but I define this column as int64 and beside it doesn't work for other columns too !!

Comment: What about the typo `blOfferList_temp` instead of `tblOfferList_temp`? Is that in your actual code?

Comment: no it is right in my actual code . I think maybe we can't modify datatable this way and I have to use a dataset instead. what do you think?

Comment: I tried that and                                                         tblOfferList_temp.AcceptChanges(); but these are not working !

Comment: Then maybe there is an error in your code somewhere else that you haven't shown us. I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: txtQuantity has an event txtQuantity_TextChanged . Does it make any difference?

Comment: It might. We don't know how any this code is being called in the first place.